# Index not used with many WHERE LOWER(column) IN (...) conditions, works fine with just a few

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.devices
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('devices_id_seq'::regclass),
  token text NOT NULL,
  ...some other columns...,
  CONSTRAINT devices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, token)
)
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_devices_lower_token ON devices (lower(token));
```

If I run the following query, everything is fine, the query runs instantly, and the index is used:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "devices"  
WHERE (id > '0') 
AND ((lower(token) IN ('92134f4bb6a2263fd044a5a04440bc1a','cbf7d4a094bd266fd3f1b7ef4196172a', 'aa0f7650cf28010b5c01b77ae206f7fb'))) 
ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000;
```

```
"Limit  (cost=58116.96..58119.46 rows=1000 width=345)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=58116.96..58189.47 rows=29005 width=345)"
"        Sort Key: id"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on devices  (cost=1061.91..56526.65 rows=29005 width=345)"
"              Recheck Cond: (lower(token) = ANY ('{92134f4bb6a2263fd044a5a04440bc1a,cbf7d4a094bd266fd3f1b7ef4196172a}'::text[]))"
"              Filter: (id > 0)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_devices_lower_token  (cost=0.00..1054.65 rows=29005 width=0)"
"                    Index Cond: (lower(token) = ANY ('{92134f4bb6a2263fd044a5a04440bc1a,cbf7d4a094bd266fd3f1b7ef4196172a}'::text[]))"
```

However, if I add a lot of conditions (e.g. 1k) for the (lower(token) IN (...)), the index will no longer be used anymore and the query will be VERY slow:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "devices"  
WHERE (id > '0') 
AND ((lower(token) IN ('92134f4bb6a2263fd044a5a04440bc1a','cbf7d4a094bd266fd3f1b7ef4196172a', 'aa0f7650cf28010b5c01b77ae206f7fb', ... up to 1k tokens ...))) 
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 1000;
```

```
"Limit  (cost=3900016.07..3900018.57 rows=1000 width=345)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=3900016.07..3907219.10 rows=2881214 width=345)"
"        Sort Key: id"
"        ->  Seq Scan on devices  (cost=0.00..3742042.21 rows=2881214 width=345)"
"              Filter: ((id > 0) AND (lower(token) = ANY ('{92134f4bb6a2263fd044a5a04440bc1a,cbf7d4a094bd266fd3f1b7ef4196172a,6116af468e0017ffe5c49309869be773,4a5ebc1cec6c452e74fbf1a4e22fe804,0a9981eaf530d22ad9fe12a73a0b486c,61eb008e86a5afeaa9edd3e56ba01e0b,a31775a866571d9c2ecadc6b2a8127a3,dfcb4bc34771883bb2a54ee44299b058,7c93581a24053021bd41b7cc4654bf9e,43182b0010cea255fef1d10849858d7c,c3f6503eafeaa1d25a6f5672310ef4e5,672641b1fcd23f67deab34deaf28f1d8,cb52e085618ecbdf6eef1669b7b38008,335626a32455e61e1b1de16550e43af0, (...)"
```

Ok so, it must not like many conditions, right?

Well, I tried replicating the same scenario but without using lower(token), and it works correctly:

```
create index IF NOT EXISTS idx_devices_token on devices (token);

SELECT * 
FROM "devices"  
WHERE (id > '0') 
AND ((token IN ('92134f4bb6a2263fd044a5a04440bc1a','cbf7d4a094bd266fd3f1b7ef4196172a', 'aa0f7650cf28010b5c01b77ae206f7fb', ... 1k tokens ...))) 
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 1000;
```

```
"Limit  (cost=25.70..25.71 rows=3 width=345)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=25.70..25.71 rows=3 width=345)"
"        Sort Key: id"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on devices  (cost=13.69..25.68 rows=3 width=345)"
"              Recheck Cond: (token = ANY ('{92134f4bb6a2263fd044a5a04440bc1a,cbf7d4a094bd266fd3f1b7ef4196172a,aa0f7650cf28010b5c01b77ae206f7fb}'::text[]))"
"              Filter: (id > 0)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_devices_token  (cost=0.00..13.69 rows=3 width=0)"
"                    Index Cond: (token = ANY ('{92134f4bb6a2263fd044a5a04440bc1a,cbf7d4a094bd266fd3f1b7ef4196172a,aa0f7650cf28010b5c01b77ae206f7fb}'::text[]))"
```

So this seems to only happen if I use an index with lower and many WHERE IN conditions.

I have no idea what is going on here, any ideas?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5

Comment: There seem to be around 2881214  rows in that table and when using the 1k values the optimizer assumes that nearly all of them are returned. Maybe increasing the statistics size on the table helps with that.

Comment: Unrelated, but: your "tokens" look suspiciously like UUIDs. If that is the case then why don't you store them in a `uuid` column? That would make the use of `lower()` completely obsolete and would also save storage space

Comment: yea, I agree if those tokens are uuids and they look like it that would make this much much more efficient.

Comment: You are right, but the tokens in the example are just random test tokens I generated, the real tokens will be android/ios/web push notification tokens, not uuids.

Comment: What's the point of `(id > '0')`? Can `id` values be negative? And why are integer values compared to a string?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I am using it for pagination (1k devices for each page), the next queries will have "id > <last_device_id>". I guess in this example it doesn't make much sense, but in reality my queries will be much more complex with several logical AND/OR groups, so that's why the pagination is needed. I also need the "order by id" to make sure there are no insertions/deletions between the queries which could cause duplicate notifications (small chance but...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that. Use [`citext`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html)

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
CREATE TABLE public.devices
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('devices_id_seq'::regclass),
  token citext NOT NULL,
  ...some other columns...,
  CONSTRAINT devices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, token)
)
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_devices_lower_token ON devices(token);
```

Then

```
AND token IN ('92134f4bb6a2263fd044a5a04440bc1a','cbf7d4a094bd266fd3f1b7ef4196172a', 'aa0f7650cf28010b5c01b77ae206f7fb', ... up to 1k tokens ...)))
```

And if you're talking about a thousand tokens you should probably use a temp table..

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE query_params ( token citext );
INSERT INTO query_params(token) VALUES ...
```

then

```
SELECT * 
FROM devices
WHERE (id > '0') 
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM query_params
  WHERE query_params.token = devices.token
)
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 1000;
```

You can even index `query_params.token`

Comment: I know Postgres is cool, but I didn't know you could have two `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik you're right. It joins SQL Server in not being *that* cool **YET.**

Comment: @EvanCarroll thanks for your answer. Your solution works great, however, at the moment I am not completely sure if I want an insensitive search for all queries, so changing the column to citext might not be the best approach. I also tried creating an index with citext (CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_devices_token_citext ON devices (citext(token));) and then change lower(token) with (token)::citext and it seems to work just as good. Do you think this is a good approach?